# why wont my nexus 10 hold a charge?

Tags: samsung-nexus-10

I've had my Nexus 10 for a while and it's been great until recently and the battery now won't hold a charge. Whenever I unplug the charger it just turns off right away and when I plug in the charger that goes from 0 percent to a hundred percent in like 5 seconds

Comment: It could be that your battery or some other piece of hardware has died, unfortunately. Have you tried different chargers or cables just to rule that out? It sounds like it would likely not help, but may be worth doing if you can.

Answer (score -1):

It may be because it came out on an earlier android version, requiring less power and battery to run. If you have a newer android version, e.g KitKat or Lollipop, it may be more intensive both visually and in terms of the power required to run it. Battery Doctor is a good application, (available on the play store), which might solve you issue.

Comment: There were issues with newer Android versions wobbling down a charge faster. But five seconds is a bit real fast (and a charger which charges a device in 5 secs is neither out for sale), so that part of your answer doesn't make much sense. Neither is the second part, as that app won't work when the device shuts down immediately.